# Is the final default argument of std::vector<bool>::resize standard?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector

My compiler (MSVC2012) has a default of `false` for the final argument of

`std::vector<bool>::resize(std::vector<bool>::size_type, bool)`

Is this standard C++ or a Microsoft extension?

I don't think it's true for the unspecialised `resize`, where any elements introduced as a result of a size increase are *not* initialised.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool doesn't seem to make it clear.

Comment: _"It's certainly not true for the unspecialised `resize`"_ That's incorrect.

Comment: Apologies, I *think* I've got the prototype correct now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

17.6.5.5  [member.functions] says:

> An implementation may declare additional non-virtual member function signatures within a class:
>   — by adding arguments with default values to a member function signature;187 *[ Note:* An implementation may not add arguments with default values to virtual, global, or non-member functions. — *end note ]*
>   — by replacing a member function signature with default values by two or more member function signatures with equivalent behavior; and
>   — by adding a member function signature for a member function name.
>   A call to a member function signature described in the C ++ standard library behaves as if the implementation declares no additional member function signatures.

This allows implementations to add/remove default arguments, so it is perfectly conforming to replace these two signatures:

```
void resize(size_type);
void resize(size_type, bool);
```

with a single function with a default argument:

```
void resize(size_type, bool = false);
```

For the non-specialized `vector<T>::resize()` the C++11 standard changed from one function (with a default argument) to two overloads, so that calling the 1-argument form no longer requires the type to be CopyConstructible. Implementations cannot use a default argument, because that would violate the last line quoted above, because the behaviour would be different.  That is irrelevant for `vector<bool>` because we always know that `bool` is CopyConstructible, so implementations can choose whether to define one `vector<bool>::resize` member function or two.

Answer (score 5):

> Is this standard C++ or a Microsoft extension?

Yes, the default argument is standard. C++11 [vector.bool] specifies

```
void resize(size_type sz, bool c = false);
```

> I don't think it's true for the unspecialised resize, where any elements introduced as a result of a size increase are not initialised.

Yes it is; although since C++11 that's achieved by two overloads, rather than a default argument, so that if you don't specify a value they are value-initialised rather than copied from a value-initialised temporary.

Comment: Plusone for mentioning the subtle change between 03 and 11.

Answer (score 3):

From the C++ Standard

```
void resize(size_type sz, bool c = false);
```

As for the general class std::vector then the function is overloaded

```
void resize(size_type sz);
void resize(size_type sz, const T& c);
```

and for the first function elements are default inserted.

I think that for `std::vector<bool>` the function could be declared like

```
void resize(size_type sz, bool c = bool());
```